# Detect duplicate JSON nodes in JSON parameter before insert in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, duplicates

I want to detect duplicate nodes from JSON before insert them in SQL Server table.

I have this stored procedure that takes a JSON parameter like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE Core.myModelEditAction
    @OrganPersonID INT,
    @SalaryItems  NVARCHAR(2000),
    @AcceptLanguage NVARCHAR(50) = "fa"
AS
    DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            INSERT INTO Core.PersonSalary (OrganPersonID, SalaryItemID, Amount)
                SELECT @OrganPersonID, SalaryItemID, Amount
                FROM OPENJSON (@SalaryItems)
                     WITH (OrganPersonID int,
                           SalaryItemID int,
                           Amount int)
```

I want to return exception if `@SalaryItems` has duplicate key

How can I detect

```sql
SELECT @OrganPersonID, SalaryItemID, Amount
FROM OPENJSON (@SalaryItems)
```

duplicate in this table in my code?

Comment: Sample data, and expected behaviour, would really help us help you. What element is your "key" in your JSON?

Comment: Did you check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#how-built-in-functions-handle-duplicate-paths) first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) without a `with` clause so that it returns the raw `key`, `value` and `type` columns, e.g.:

```sql
declare @SalaryItems nvarchar(2000) = N'{
  "OrganPersonID": 1,
  "SalaryItemID": 1,
  "Amount": 1,
  "SalaryItemID": 1,
  "SalaryItemID": 1
}';

-- Detect duplicated keys...
select [key], count(1) as count
from openjson(@SalaryItems)
group by [key]
having count(1) > 1;
```

```
key           count
------------- -----
SalaryItemID      3
```

Comment: This seems a little odd I must admit though; if the OP only wants to pass one value per element, why not use scalar parameters for each? If this is the correct interpretation of the problem then this feels like an XY Problem.

Comment: Beats me, I just volunteer here.

Comment: I'm not saying the answer is wrong, don't worry, just that if this *is* right that the OP should be rethinking their application code.